# How does a thermoelectric generator generates electricity?

Tags: peltier, thermocouple, electricity

I want to know how a thermoelectric generator generates electricity. I know that it converts 'heat flow' to electricity.But some people say it consumes heat and converts it into electricity.The rest of the heat is dissipated  through the other side. Which is true?

Comment: You're looking for the "Seebeck effect".

Comment: Yeah I know according to seebeck effect a thermoelectric generator generates electricity from heat flow but somebody is telling it converts heat to electricity. But according to seebeck effect it converts 'heat flow' to electricity. I just want to know which is true actually

Comment: The answer is Quantum Physics. For a simplistic model of how it works, look up "Maxwell's Demon".

Comment: If there isn't a cold side, it stops generating. So "heat" alone doesn't make it work, there must be a thermal gradient and, yes, heat flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It converts some (a small fraction) of the heat flow to electricity. It absorbs X amount of heat from the hot side, and rejects X-delta amount to the cold side. The output voltage is related to the temperature difference between the hot and cold sides. The output current is related to delta, the heat flow difference.

Because present devices are very inefficient, without taking very careful measurements, measurements that are beyond most hobbyists to do accurately, it would be easy to conclude that it doesn't consume any heat at all. X-delta is very similar in magnitude to X. A small difference between two big measurements has been the bane of experimenters since antiquity!

So people that say 'it converts heat flow to electricity', or 'it converts heat to electricity', are both correct, up to a hand-wavy approximation. It needs both.

Comment: that means absorbed heat= rejected heat?

Comment: No, read it again!

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean by 'X-delta'? and if it doesn't consume heat at all, the absorbed heat and rejected heat should be equal.

Comment: I think you are trolling me, winding me up. But let's assume you are not. I am using algebra. X represents an unknown amount of heat. Delta is a convention for something small, in this context something small compared to X. So using example numbers of X=4, delta = 0.1 for instance, then X-delta would then be 3.9. The context continues with X-delta being 'a similar magnitude to X', and 'the output current related to delta, the heat flow difference'. I fail to see how it could be misunderstood, given that you cared enough about the subject to ask the question.

Comment: That means Δ heat will be converted into electricity?                   you mean if absorbed heat=x and rejected heat=y then generated electricity=x-y?

Comment: 'Generated electricity=x-y' is not correct. However, x-y less heat is discharged to the cold side, due to the generation of electricity by the flow of heat **is** correct. The words I used in the answer were 'is related to', and those words are less open to over-interpretation.

Comment: Then where does the (x-y) heat go? does this heat convert into electricity?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a part of the heat flow and generates electricity from it.

However, there must be a heat *flow*; otherwise you'd have a [perpetual motion machine of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#Classification), and that is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to really be a physics question about heat engines.  Anything that converts energy from a heat difference into some other form is a heat engine.  In this case, you are apparently asking about one of the ways of converting a heat difference into a electric potential directly.  What the output is (electric power, rotating shaft, etc) makes no difference.  When the input is a heat difference, you have a heat engine.

Heat engines are limited by the *Carnot efficiency*:

Efficiency = (T<sub>hot</sub> - T<sub>cold</sub>)/T<sub>hot</sub>

The temperatures must be in a linear absolute scale, like degrees Kelvin.

For example, to extract power from reservoirs of boiling water (373°K) and ice water (273°K), the best you can ever do is 27% efficiency.  This means that if you were to extract 10 W from this setup with a theoretical perfect heat engine, there would actually be 37 W of heat flowing from the hot reservoir to the cold reservoir.

This basic physics applies to heat engines with electric output too, like thermocouples and thermionic generators.  The main difference is that real heat engines won't achieve 100% of the possible Carnot efficiency.  In a thermistor, for example, there is significant heat flow along each wire that is not converted to a electric potential.  The heat gradient along the wire produces the electric potential, but also provides a heat leakage path.

Comment: 37W flowing out of the hot reservoir and 27W flowing into the cold reservoir.